# Android 8 how to determine what default app opens png

Tags: android

In Android 8 how do you determine what is the default app that opens a png?  I have an app that when we show a link for a png and you tap on the png, it opens an app however it appears that app crashes and returns.  I know you can go to the settings -> Apps&Notifications and clear defaults. But how do I find out which app is opening up when a png is pressed?

Comment: Hey dan, did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: No I have not.  Can't imagine that this is that hard.